# progress bar inside fragment cuts off at top and bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I wanted to implement a timer that has a circle around it that gradually disappears as the timer starts to run down. The problem that I am having is that the fragment that contains the progress bar won't scale to fit the container that it is in and cuts off at the top and bottom. I got a feeling that this is a height related issue because if I increase the height of the container that contains the fragment, the progress bar works as expected again.

This image shows that the circular progress bar is cut-off at the top and the bottom
[image: Image that shows the cut-off at the top and bottom]

In this image I increased the height of the parent and the cut-off problem is fixed but this solution is not good for my purposes.
[image: Image that shows that cut-off does not happen if I increase the parent heigth]

Here are my xml files

shape_ring_color_yellow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:toDegrees="0">
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <solid android:color="@color/colorCountDownTimerYellow" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

count_down_timer_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBarCircle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progressBarCircle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progressBarCircle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBarCircle" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarCircle"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_ring_color_yellow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The partial XML for the layout that uses the count_down_timer_fragment.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bubblewall.saik.bubblewall.RemoteControlBubbleWall"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient_color_light_blue">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_control_buttons"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline_10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_on_off"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_gradient_green_black_border"
            android:text="@string/on" />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/countDownTimerFragment"
            android:name="com.bubblewall.saik.bubblewall.CountDownTimerFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            tools:layout="@layout/count_down_timer_fragment" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_sleep"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background_gradient_yellow_black_border"
            android:text="@string/sleep"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint_layout_sleep_button_and_timer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraint_layout_sleep_button_and_timer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraint_layout_sleep_button_and_timer"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraint_layout_sleep_button_and_timer" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

At this point I tried everything. I tried setting the layout gravity to center, I try to change the scaleType but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I was finally able to solve the problem. From what I can understand, this was happening because progress bar was scaling horizontally in the linear layout and it was creating the situation where the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the progress bar were different. Surprisingly I was unable to find a solution that I can use in my layout files and I ended up writing code to solve this issue. What I basically did was to set padding either on the height or on the width to make sure that the content inside the fragment has equal height and width. Here is the code that handles that.

This code is inside my fragment class.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.count_down_timer_fragment, container, false);

        root.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int fragmentHeight=root.getMeasuredHeight();
                int fragmentWidth = root.getMeasuredWidth();
                CustomLogger.log("------------------------- H: " + fragmentHeight + " W: " + fragmentWidth, 'i');
                if(fragmentWidth > fragmentHeight){
                    root.setPadding((fragmentWidth - fragmentHeight) / 2, 0, (fragmentWidth - fragmentHeight) / 2, 0);
                } else {
                    root.setPadding(0, (fragmentHeight - fragmentWidth) / 2, 0, (fragmentHeight - fragmentWidth) / 2);
                }
            }
        });

        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **TRICK** way to do that because you do **NOT** want your buttons to stretch and become bigger.
 **DO THIS:**
 In one of your `Buttons` (lets say on_off_button) you shall have to add this lines **:**

```
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
```

Then in that same `Button` increase the amount of values  to `2dp` then to `3dp` then to `4dp` and so on while keeping an eye to your circular progress, until you are satisfied on how your circular value looks good and full. But remember both values has to be the same this will balance the top and bottom and so the `Button` will be centred.

After that copy and paste the margins values to the other remaining `Button` so that they can be equal up to that they now look equal.

Comment: I see what you are saying but my concern with this solution is that it will basically make the buttons smaller to accommodate the progress bar correct?

Comment: I got you, so you want to reduce the size of progress bar?

Comment: Exactly and the problem I had was that progress bar was getting reduced horizontally and this was cutting off the top and bottom. I fixed it now by doing what I wrote above.